# What is the average degree of a d-simplex?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complexes, definitions

I am a beginner in network topology topics and while I was reading an article about simplicial complexes where the authors had used random simplicial complexes, I came across a formula using "average degree of a d-simplex". I have been looking at other articles online but I couldn't get a simple definition. I was wondering if anyone could help me understand
what is the average degree of a d-simplex?
Does it exist for all simplicial complexes (both random and not random)?
How do we calculate it?

Any help on finding the answer to these questions is very appreciated!

Comment: Every vertex of a $d$-simplex has degree $d$ (e.g., tetrahedron vertices in $\mathbb{R}^3$ have degree $3$), so there must be a different notion of "average degree," different from the straightforward meaning of the term. Maybe it means the average degree of a simplex that is part of a random complex.

Comment: Maybe it means the average number of incident d-simplexes to a random d-simplex selected from the complex.